# AutoHotKey Mouse Bindings

Tags: autohotkey

I want the hotkey to activate when I click <kbd>X</kbd>. Then it should:

- Click LMB
- Pause 5 ticks
- Click RMB

And then finished. But for some reason it's not working for me. I've already tried it and looked at other threads. If anyone could help it would be fantastic.

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by *5 ticks*? If you want to set a timeout for 5 ms or seconds, you should use the **Sleep** parameter as follows:

```
Sleep 5 ; milliseconds
Sleep 5000 ; 5 seconds (5000 ms)
Sleep % var ; if you need to use a variable instead of number
```

There is also a variable called **A_TickCount**

```
tick := A_TickCount
while(tick + 5 < A_TickCount) ; 5 ticks
    continue
; I guess this code will execute in 0.1 ms, so try to turn the tick up
```

In your case:

```
click
sleep 5000 ; change this if necessary
click right
```

It works fine for me.
Learn more about `Click`: https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Click.htm